# How to install .NET Core 3 application on pure Ubuntu Core Snappy

Tags: snap, ubuntu-core, raspberrypi, c#

I have a pure Ubuntu Core Snappy build running on a Raspberry Pi 3.  My new requirement is a to add a C# application based on .NET Core 3.

I can't find an existing Snap supporting .NET Core 3 and a dependent application.  Need advice on how to generate one.

Comment: Probably you should stick with instruction line this https://gist.github.com/richlander/467813274cea8abc624553ee72b28213

Comment: if you go to the dotnet plugin page: https://snapcraft.io/docs/dotnet-plugin there is (like on all snapcraft plugin pages) a link pointing to github examples using that plugin ...